# ASP JSON: Multidimensional JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, asp-classic

How should I access the "games" array within this JSON? I'm using the class from http://aspjson.com.

```
{
"period":[
  {
     "period_id":"1774",
     "start_time_epoch":1431126300,
     "games":[
        {
           "home_team":"WSH",
           "away_team":"ATL"
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Method of access:

```
today = date

For Each key In oJSON.data("period")
  Set this  = oJSON.data("period").item(key)

    periodID    = this.item("period_id")
    periodDate  = FormatDateTime(DateAdd("s", this.item("start_time_epoch"), "01/01/1970 00:00:00"),2)

    ----Ideally, this.item("games").item("home_team") would have worked.----
    if cstr(today) = periodDate then
        response.write periodID & " - " & periodDate &  "<br/> - " & this.item("games").item("start_time")
    end if

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

This would be valid:

```
{
   "period":[
      {
         "period_id":"1774",
         "start_time_epoch":1431126300,
         "games":[
            {
               "home_team":"WSH",
               "away_team":"ATL"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

To access the home team you can use

```
Response.Write( oJSON.data("period")(0)("games")(0)("home_team"))
```

Comment: Thanks. The JSON that I have in my question was simplified.